# Disconnection On Classic bluetooth legacy pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

**Issue:** Our Bluetooth version is 4.2. But I am trying to pair with legacy pairing method with phones because of some pin key based requirement. So that, I have disabled Secure simple pairing and Secure connections in the system.

I could enter 4 digit pin on my mobile and get request on the device as well. The 4 digit digit "0000" hard coded pin has sent as a response to phone.Based on that,bonding/pairing also completed. But it has failed on the connection because of **authentication failure** and **Connection terminated by local host**.

what could be the reason here ? can you help me ?, I have attached the images from btsnoop_hci.log

Disconnection sent - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fyx1.png,

Disconnection events - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kuNF.png,

Disconnect complete - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP2NX.png

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from the images, it looks like pairing and authentication is not getting completed. We require complete snoop logs to confirm why your device is sending disconnect command. If possible please share the snoop logs. Also can you check with other phones and confirm the behavior if it is same.

Does your device is seen in paired list on the mobile phone? As host is sending disconnect command with reason code authentication failure suggests that both device is not paired. So can you confirm